# Ubuntu 10.04 server as a transparent proxy filter (plus dans guardian)

Tags: 10.04, server, transparent-proxy

I've installed the Server on a desktop with two network cards. 
I've installed dnsmasq, squid, shorewall, ssh, and dansguardian.

how do I get this device to talk to DSL modem and my network (through my router)

I've configured the network cards to separate networks.
I've set up the DHCP/DNC settings  (I did not install dhcp3-server, using dnsmasq).

I've tried following these instructions as guide line.
http://taksuyama.com/?p=16

Any help would be great.  These are great devices when they work for homes with kids!

Comment: 'These are great devices when they work for homes with kids'  -- Yes, and helpful for the occasional grown-up too.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a router hooked up to your DSL modem by way of the router's "internet" port, then this complicates things. Essentially you want to replace that router with a linux router that has the desired capabilities.

So the recommended setup would be

(internet)=----=[dsl modem]=----=[server w/ 2 nics]=-----=[LAN port of router/wifi AP/etc]---> all of your computers

Doing it this way should make the linked HOWTO work. You'll need to disable DHCP and UPnP on the router too, as that may interfere with your Linux's server's functioning.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. 
The first problem I'm having is the Linux box talking to the modem.  
I've disabled the dhcp on the router and the PPPOE.

I can't get pppoeconf to talk negotate a connection

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your firewall (shorewall) in such a way that all outgoing packages that represent web traffic, i.e. ports 80, 443 will be forwarded to the same host (127.0.0.1) and the port on which your dansguardian process is listening too. This way there is no direct connection for these ports to the outside anymore, but all are filtered by dansguardian.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.  
I know I set some of that up.  I'll double check it.